# Create CRM entity record with Async approach

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I need to create CRM entity record asynchronously. I have implemented multi threading in my code and each thread will be responsible to create an entity record in the CRM. Right now due to the blocking behavior of CRM while creating the entity I am unable to utilize the opened threads.

Following is the code which I want to perform in asynchronous way.

```
Entity task = new Entity("task");
task["subject"] = "Test Task";
task["description"] = "Testing";
task["regardingobjectid"] =  new EntityReference("account", new Guid("xxxxxxxxxxxx"));
Guid taskid = service.Create(task);
```

Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `CreateAsync` example from the BaseProxyClass of [XrmToolkit](https://xrmtoolkit.com)

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(IOrganizationService service)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => { return this.Create(service); });
}
```